# How can I use a template in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, types

I wish to use a template that has a default parameter `l` in class A, but the program produces errors:

```
class B {
 public:
  B(){
  ...
  }
}

template <int l = 1>
class A {
    public: 
  A(const B& b){
  ...
  }
}

int main(){
  B b;

  A(b) a; // error: missing template arguments before '(' token
  A<5>(b) a;    // error: expected ';' before 'a'
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Get a C++ book.  SO isn't intended for simple syntax questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because it's a templated class doesn't change the initialization syntax:

```
  A<5> a(b);
```

Using the defaulted parameter:

```
  A<> a(b);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
A<> a(b);
A<5> a(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try
    A<> a(b);
to get the default.

Answer (score 1):

you need a semicolon after your class definitions.

Answer (score 0):

`A` is a template, so you'll have to provide the template brackets irrespective of whether or not it is supplied with a default value.

```
A<> a(b);
```

If you don't want to use the template brackets, you can use a `typedef` declaration to avoid it:

```
typedef A<> X;
```

The other errors you are experiencing are due to the fact that you did not end your class definitions with a semicolon.

Here is a working program -- http://ideone.com/occE71#view_edit_box